# Dependências não satisfeitas - SpringFramewok

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Olá!

Estou estudando Spring e estou com seguinte problema para subir o projeto no tomcat8. Minha dependências não estão sendo injetadas, porém não estou conseguindo identificar o que está faltando.

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClass}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${connection.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${connection.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${connection.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${connection.maxIdleTime}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gervasios.sgr.entidades"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>sgr Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Interface UsuarioDAO**

```
public interface IUsuarioDAO {
    void salvarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws PersistenceException; 
}
```

**UsuarioDAO**

```
@Repository
public class UsuarioDAO extends CrudDAO<Usuario, Serializable> implements IUsuarioDAO {
    public void salvarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws PersistenceException {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(usuario);
    }
}
```

**Interface UsuarioBO**

```
public interface IUsuarioBO {
    void salvarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws TransactionException;
}
```

**UsuarioBO**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UsuarioBO implements IUsuarioBO {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;

    public void salvarUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws TransactionException{
        usuarioDAO.salvarUsuario(usuario);
    }
}
```

**UsuarioControler**

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioControler {

    @Autowired    
    private IUsuarioBO usuarioBO;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value={"/saveNewUser"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String salvar(@Valid Usuario usuario, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "cadastroUsuario";
        }
        usuarioBO.salvarUsuario(usuario);
        return "sucess";
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Javax - Jsf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql-Conector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**ERRO**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioBO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gervasios.sgr.dao.api.IUsuarioDAO com.gervasios.sgr.bo.UsuarioBO.usuarioDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gervasios.sgr.dao.api.IUsuarioDAO com.gervasios.sgr.bo.UsuarioBO.usuarioDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
    at com.gervasios.sgr.hibernate.HibernateSession.getSession(HibernateSession.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 42 more
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu problema foi uma falta de atenção com minha classe para obter um Session do Hibernate.

**Como estava**

```
@Repository
public abstract class HibernateSession {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

**Alterada**

```
@Repository
public abstract class HibernateSession {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda utluiz.

Answer (score 0):

A causa original do problema está na última exceção do log:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

O erro da injeção não foi causada por falta de classes como `ClassNotFoundException`, o que seria um sintoma de problemas com dependências.

Isso é causado porque o Spring não conseguiu obter uma transação para as classes onde você usou o `@Transactional`, portanto não conseguiu criá-las corretamente e todas as classes que dependem dela também não serão criadas.

Vi que você configurou corretamente transações no seu XML usando `<tx:annotation-driven/>`, o que geralmente é a causa desse erro, então o problema está em outro lugar.

Infelizmente não consigo ver o motivo porque o Spring não conseguiu criar a documentação, mas pode ter algo a ver com falha ao conectar com o banco ou com o pool de conexões.

Sugiro remover a anotação de transação e ver se funciona sem isso.

Também ajudaria aumentar o nível de log e reparar se antes disso ocorre algum alerta ou erro de qualquer natureza. Há algum tempo tive alguns colegas tendo problemas estranhos com banco e quando analisei o log cuidadosamente vi que o Spring Boot não estava ignorando as configurações do banco de dados e criando um banco em memória. Isso porque o arquivo de configuração não estava no local correto no projeto.

Se conseguir mais alguma informação, edite a sua pergunta que tentarei ajudar mais.

Por fim, sugiro também usar o [HirakiCP](http://phttps://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) para gerenciar o pool de conexões. Ele tem desempenho e estabilidade bem melhores que bibliotecas antigas como Apache DBCP e C3P0.

Comment: Tudo bem utluiz, obrigado pela resposta. Vou verificar e respondo se conseguir mais detalhes.